# Jetpack Compose deriveStateOf side effect cannot work along snapshotFlow side effect?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I have the below code, all works (i.e. When scrolling past the first row, a button appears. When scrolling past the second row, another button appears)

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun TestSnapshotFlow() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(state = listState) {
            items(1000) { index ->
                Text(text = "Item: $index")
            }
        }

        var showButtonSnapshot by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        val showButtonDerive by remember(listState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
            mutableStateOf(
                listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
            )
        }

        Log.d("Track", "Recompose")
        Column {
            AnimatedVisibility(showButtonDerive) {
                Button({}) {
                    Text("Row 1 hiding")
                }
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(showButtonSnapshot) {
                Button({}) {
                    Text("Row 1 and 2 hiding")
                }
            }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(listState) {
            snapshotFlow { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
                .map { index -> index > 2 }
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect {
                    Log.d("Track", "B $it")
                    showButtonSnapshot = it
                }
        }
    }
}
```

However, If I change

```
val showButtonDerive by remember(listState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
    mutableStateOf(
        listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
    )
}
```

to the DeriveStateOf

```
val showButtonDerive by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
    }
}
```

It doesn't work as expected anymore. The second button won't appear. (even though I check that the `collect` did trigger and and change `showButtonSnapshot` to true, the recomposition didn't happen anymore).

Looks like `deriveStateOf` and `snapshotFlow` can't work together to trigger the recompose. Separate them out individually works.

**Just for easier copy-&-paste to test, the full code that doesn't work as expected as below**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun TestSnapshotFlow() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(state = listState) {
            items(1000) { index ->
                Text(text = "Item: $index")
            }
        }

        var showButtonSnapshot by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        val showButtonDerive by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
            }
        }

        Log.d("Track", "Recompose")
        Column {
            AnimatedVisibility(showButtonDerive) {
                Button({}) {
                    Text("Row 1 hiding")
                }
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(showButtonSnapshot) {
                Button({}) {
                    Text("Row 1 and 2 hiding")
                }
            }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(listState) {
            snapshotFlow { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
                .map { index -> index > 2 }
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect {
                    Log.d("Track", "B $it")
                    showButtonSnapshot = it
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bug is filed at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215402574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing everything right, and recomposition isn't triggered when it should. I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

As a tmp solution you can update the value from an other coroutine scope, for example from `MainScope()`:

```
snapshotFlow { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
    .map { index -> index > 2 }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .collect {
        MainScope().launch {
            showButtonSnapshot = it
        }
    }
```